# Adding degrees of freedom in lm summary

Tags: r, lm

i am using this code to run a lot of simple linear regression at the same time, in the output i get the R_squard and p value, however i want also to add the total degrees of freedom to the output, how should i adapt the code so that total degrees of freedom is also added to my output?

```
lm_output = lm(test[,1] ~ test_2[,1])

Output_1 <- data.frame(R_spuared = summary(lm_output)$r.squared)
Output_1$P_value <- summary(lm_output)$coefficients[2,4]
Output_1$Variabele <- paste(colnames(test))
Output_1$Variabele_1 <- paste(colnames(test_2))
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
summary(lm_output)$fstatistic
```

The second and third number are the df's for the F-Test.